# journalctl - How to clear until last boot?

Tags: systemd, logs, systemd-journald, journalctl

I'm aware of `journalctl`'s `vacuum-time`, `vacuum-size` and `vacuum-files`. Is there a way to do `vacuum-boot` or something similar? Yes, this can be accomplished by specifying a specific time, however, pin pointing an exact time is rather practically difficult.

Is there a way to say, clear everything until the current boot, last 2 boots, etc?

Comment: Find the times you need with `journalctl --list-boots`

Comment: `vacuum-time` actually takes spans in the form of "s, h, d, years", etc. Not in a standard time form, if I'm right? So, doesn't seem like I can give in an exact time easily.